# Error al llamar a un método de otra clase

Tags: java, android

Desde mi clase `GuiaParte2` intento llamar a un método de `MainActivity` pero se cierra mi aplicación con lo siguiente en el

`logcat`

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

`GuiaParte2`

```
@Override
public void onSwipe(int direction) {
    switch (direction) {


        case GestosActivity.SWIPE_DOWN:

            // llamo al método de MainActivity

            MainActivity a = new MainActivity();
            a.editarPersona(0);

            // finalizo la clase

            this.finish();
    }
}
```

`MainActivity`

```
   public void editarPersona(int p_id){
        // Si el p_id es 0, entonces se crea una nueva persona.
        if(p_id == 0){
            // Se dirige a la actividad CrearPersonaActivity.
            Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CrearPersonaActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(actividad_editarPersona, CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA);
        }else{
            // Recupera una persona especifica.
            Persona persona;

            try{
                persona = baseDatos.getPersona(p_id);

                // Se dirige a la actividad CrearPersonaActivity.
                Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(this, EditarPersonaActivity.class);

                // Se le coloca parametros para enviar a la actividad CrearPersonaActivity.
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("id", p_id);
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("nombre", persona.getNombre());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("fecha", persona.getFecha());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("zodiaco", persona.getZodiaco());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("edad", persona.getEdad());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("diasrestantes", persona.getDiasrestantes());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("ruta_imagen", persona.getRutaImagen());
                startActivityForResult(actividad_editarPersona, CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (getResources().getString(R.string.error_editar)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                baseDatos.cerrar();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cuando lanzas la aplicación, se llama a la clase MainActivity? Por el nombre que le has puesto (Main), yo entiendo que si. Si es el caso... no puedes crear otra instancia de la clase que contiene a la vista. La solución más facil es hacer el método: public static void editarPersona(int p_id){} Y cuando quieras llamarlo,no creas una nueva instancia (new), si no que lo llamas: MainActivity.editarPersona(0);

Comment: Efectivamente es la clase principal, pero si hago `static` al método obtengo muchos errores al compilar, y todos comienzan igual "not-static variable/method..." @FIPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que no esta muy bien pensada la lógica de este programa, puesto a que no se por que el mainActivity tiene un método que se llama editarPersona.

Crea una clase que se llame Persona y escribe ahi todos los métodos que tengan relación con ella. como editarPersona.

Asi mantienes un orden en el código. Puesto que tu clase Persona sera el modelo y puedes modificarlo todo desde ahi. Creas una instancia de persona en vez del mainActivity. y el metodo editarPersona lo pones como público y estático. y no deberias tener problemas con lo que intentas hacer.

Tambien revisa los imports que hagas en tus clases, pues depende de como declares la clase y con que modificadores de acceso los pongas.

Comment: Gracias por tu consejo, estoy intentando ordenar los métodos en una misma clase, pero estoy teniendo problemas, si puedes pásate: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55801/problemas-al-ordenar-m%C3%A9todos-en-una-misma-clase @Luis