# Problemas al ordenar métodos en una misma Clase y llamarlo desde otra

Tags: java, android

Siguiendo el consejo que me dieron en otra pregunta estoy ordenando mi código y para ello quiero poner los métodos en una misma `clase` para así llamarlo en las `clases` que los necesite, pero estoy teniendo problemas, os explico:

He creado una `clase` llamada `MetodosPersonas` y aquí estoy incluyendo los métodos, son métodos para editar y borrar las Personas de mi `ListView` que relleno con `Sqlite`, en este caso el método es para borrar.

`MetodosPersonas`

```
 public class MetodosPersonas extends Activity {

    DatabaseHandler baseDatos;

    public void eliminarPersona(int id_persona) {
        AlertDialog.Builder mensaje_dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final int v_id_persona = id_persona;
        mensaje_dialogo.setTitle("Importante");
        mensaje_dialogo.setMessage("¿Está seguro de eliminar esta persona?");
        mensaje_dialogo.setCancelable(false);
        mensaje_dialogo.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                try {
                    baseDatos.eliminaPersona(v_id_persona);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al eliminar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    baseDatos.cerrar();
                }
            }
        });
        mensaje_dialogo.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
            }
        });
        mensaje_dialogo.show();
    }
}
```

Lo llamo así en `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_contextual_eliminar_persona:
            MetodosPersonas a = new MetodosPersonas();
            a.eliminarPersona((int)info.id);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item);
    }
}
```

Pero se me cierra la aplicación al hacer clic en `menu_contextual_eliminar_persona`, recibo esto en `LogCat`

```
03-16 21:53:11.566 27361-27368/? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
03-16 21:53:16.191 27361-27361/otrointento.dos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: otrointento.dos, PID: 27361
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:149)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:222)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:452)
    at otrointento.dos.MetodosPersonas.eliminarPersona(MetodosPersonas.java:15)
    at otrointento.dos.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:102)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3224)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$PhoneWindowMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3671)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1182)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3147)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4062)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Si utilizo ese mismo método desde la clase `MainActivity` sin pasar por `MetodosPersonas` funciona perfectamente, pero si quiero utilizar el método en `MainActivity` desde `MetodosPersonas` obtengo el error que comento arriba.

Dejo aquí mi `DatabaseHandler` por si es necesario.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    // Ruta por defecto de las bases de datos en el sistema Android.
    private static String RUTA_BASE_DATOS = "/data/data/otrointento.dos/databases/";

    // Nombre de la Base de Datos.
    private static String NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS = "BDBIRTHDAY_INFO";

    // Version de la Base de Datos.
    private static final int VERSION_BASE_DATOS = 1;

    // Objeto Base de Datos.
    private SQLiteDatabase base_datos;

    // Objeto Contexto.
    private Context contexto;

    // Constante privada
    private String SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS = "CREATE TABLE if not exists personas (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, " +
            "nombre TEXT, fecha TEXT, ruta_imagen TEXT)";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS, null, VERSION_BASE_DATOS);
        this.contexto = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Se ejecuta la sentencia SQL de creación de la tabla personas.
        db.execSQL(SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Se elimina la versión anterior de la tabla Personas.
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Personas");

        // Se crea la nueva versión de la tabla personas.
        db.execSQL(SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS);
    }

    public long insertarPersona(Persona persona){
        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
        valores.put("nombre", persona.getNombre());
        valores.put("fecha", persona.getFecha());
        valores.put("ruta_imagen", persona.getRutaImagen());
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert("Personas", null, valores);
    }

    public void actualizarRegistros(int id, String nombre, String fecha, String ruta_imagen){
        ContentValues actualizarDatos = new ContentValues();
        actualizarDatos.put("nombre", nombre);
        actualizarDatos.put("fecha", fecha);
        actualizarDatos.put("ruta_imagen", ruta_imagen);
        String where = "_id=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};

        try{
            this.getReadableDatabase().update("Personas", actualizarDatos, where, whereArgs);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            String error =  e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que retorna una persona especifica.
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    public Persona getPersona(int p_id) {
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"_id", "nombre", "fecha", "ruta_imagen"};
        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Personas", columnas, "_id" + "= " + p_id, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Persona persona = new Persona(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));

        // Retorna la persona especifica.
        return persona;
    }

    public void cerrar(){
        this.close();
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que devuelve todas las personas.
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor obtenerTodasPersonas(){
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"_id", "nombre", "fecha", "ruta_imagen"};
        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Personas", columnas, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }


    /**
     * Metodo publico que elimina una persona especifica.
     * @param rowId
     * @return
     */
    public boolean eliminaPersona(int id){
        return this.getWritableDatabase().delete("Personas", "_id" + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, sigo sin solución :/

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios problemas:

1º. Si has declarado la clase `DatabaseHandler` con este constructor:

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS, null, VERSION_BASE_DATOS);
        this.contexto = context;
    }
```

Al crear una nueva instancia de la clase, esto es incorrecto:

```
    baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler();
```

¿por qué? porque si te fijas, el método `public DatabaseHandler (Context context) {` espera un parámetro que es el contexto.

Entonces, la forma de crear la instancia de la clase sería:

```
    baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

`this` en el caso de que estés llamando la nueva instancia desde la clase de la actividad principal o bien,

```
    baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
```

en el caso de que estés fuera de la actividad principal y esta sea la clase `MainActivity`

2º. El tipo de dato que pasas al método :

```
   public boolean eliminaPersona(long id){
        return this.getWritableDatabase().delete("Personas", "_id" + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }
```

es incorrecto. Aquí lo has declarado como del tipo `long` mientras que en la llamada, le pasas un `int`

```
    final int v_id_persona = id_persona;

    baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler();
    baseDatos.eliminaPersona(v_id_persona);
```

Hay más cosas que se pueden mejorar, aquí sólo indico las dos cosas que veo que hacen que tu programa falle.

Lo demás se puede mejorar más adelante.

Comment: Prueba de esta manera: `baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(PersonasM.this);`

Comment: Al declarar tu variable de BD: `static DatabaseHandler baseDatos;` declara mejor `DatabaseHandler baseDatos;`

Comment: Para llamarlo desde otra clase tiene que ser `public`, mientras que `static` se refiere a métodos o campos que no tienen dependencia de otros campos o valores de la clase.

Comment: Ya me he perdido.. Yo lo que necesito es una clase a parte de todas donde tenga los métodos y esos métodos poderlos llamar desde cualquier clase..

Comment: Lo sé. Lo que quiero decirte es que para poder llamar un método de una clase desde fuera de ella el método tiene que ser declarado como `public`, o sea que el hecho de declarar un método `static` no lo hace por eso disponible para usarse desde fuera de la clase.

Comment: He editado la pregunta, a ver si ahora lo podemos solucionar, gracias @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente el problema que estas teniendo es que estas intentando ejecutar el método `baseDatos.eliminaPersona(v_id_persona);` sin haber inicializado el objeto `baseDatos`, de ahí el null que te está saltando.

Antes de llamar al método deberías inicializar el objeto:

```
public class PersonasM {

    static DatabaseHandler baseDatos;

    public static void eliminarPersona(int id_persona){

        final int v_id_persona = id_persona;

        baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler();
        baseDatos.eliminaPersona(v_id_persona);
        baseDatos.cerrar();

    }
}
```

Comment: He editado la pregunta @Monclus